# Using individual tex files for individual figures

Tags: floats, formatting

Is there any problems in the future if I use individual .tex files for individual figures? For example, instead of having the code below,

```
some text 

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \includegraphics[scale=1.7]{birds.jpg}
  \caption{The birds}
  \label{fig:birds}
\end{figure}

some more text
```

it would be something like this.

```
some text

\insert{figure_about_birds.tex}

some more text
```

figure_about_birds.tex would be the section of code below.

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \includegraphics[scale=1.7]{birds.jpg}
  \caption{The birds}
  \label{fig:birds}
\end{figure}
```

It might be a hassle to try to go back and fix the formatting of the figure, but I think the main .tex file will read a lot better if it is like this. I also don't want to do something naughty that will hurt me in the future.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site!  I don't know which tools you're using, but with the right editor you could keep all the lines in your one file and use cold folding to streamline the look.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_folding

Comment: Cool! I use overleaf, and it looks like that is an option. I guess one problem with it is that the figure name does not show when it is folded. It just says "
\begin{figure}<-> \end{figure}". Regardless, it is a neat trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\input` for this (there is no `\insert` command in latex by default). That should have no issues at all.

Unrelated though: you should not use `[h!]` LaTeX will usually warn about that and change the option.

Answer (score 1):

`keyfloat` package provides an equally short syntax without making editing of additional files necessary:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{keyfloat}

\begin{document}

some text 

\keyfig[h!]{s=.5,c={The birds},l={fig:birds}}{birds}

some more text

\end{document}
```